# What message have the aliens sent us?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Disclaimer** This question came in an exam whose solution is available on the internet. So please do not  google it's solution. I have modified the question slightly. Thanks.

So........

---

An alien civilization on a star far far away came to know about Earth and wanted to test smartness of humans.

They sent the following message in the form of ones and zeros.

**Message 1**

They sent it in the form of ones and zeros. Find out what it says.

> 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 11111 01100 00100 00100 00011
>   10000 01000 10100 01000 10100 01101 10000 10001 00100 10001 11000
>   10001 00001 00010 00101 00100 01001 10110 01111 10100 00110 10000
>   01001 11000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 000

**Tip**
The coded message is a abbreviation which may not make much sense.

**What is the message?**

All the best, earthlings!

---

<sub>Source of question : http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/inaoSr2010-S.pdf</sub>

<sub>*Also this is my first question on this site, so please tell me if this question is a appropriate post on this site.*</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Is this from an ongoing contest?

Comment: No, I'll link the question paper. It is from INAO 2010 exam.

Comment: http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/inaoSr2010-S.pdf

Comment: Please go to question 14

Comment: Cool. Also, it's nice to mention the source(as you have) once you accept an answer. Enjoy your time on Puzzling.SE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you

> Align digits by lines of 29

You get :

> 00000000000000000000000000000
>  0**11111**0 **11**0000**1**0000**1**00000**111**00
>  000**1**000**1**0**1**000**1**000**1**0**1**000**11**0**11**0
>  000**1**000**1**00**1**00**1**000**111**000**1**000**1**0
>  000**1**000**1**000**1**0**1**00**1**000**1**00**11**0**11**0
>  0**11111**0 **1**0000**11**0**1**00000**1**00**111**00
>  00000000000000000000000000000

And we can read

> INAO

Comment: That is the full solution. Wow, this site is nice:)

Comment: Also, I am new to puzzling, so I don't understand what you did, what does formatted message mean?

Comment: And here I was, saying , if someone finds it's unsolvable.......    and the question is solved in 5 minutes!  I realize I must have sounded obnoxious.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe that's clearer now